# How to select part of an image, then paste the selected part of the image in a checkerboard pattern into another image using JES?

Tags: python, jython, jes

I am using `Jython`, or `JES`, and I want to repeatedly copy, in a checkerboard pattern, part of one image into another image. I am wondering how that might be done?

So far I have this:

```
def checkerboard(pic):
  p = makeEmptyPicture(500,500)
  targetX = 100
  for sourceX in range(81,123):
    targetY = 100
    for sourceY in range(99,126):
      color = getColor(getPixel(pic,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(p,targetX,targetY),color)
      targetY = targetY + 1
    targetX = targetX + 1
  show(p)
```

`Pic` is the user selected image, and `picX` and `picY` are the ranges of the picture.
The issue is that this just pastes part of an image once into the empty picture (`p`). I want the part of the image to be pasted repeatedly into the empty picture in a certain area of the empty picture.

Comment: what is `makeEmptyPicture()`, `getPixel()`, `getColor()`, `setColor()` ? Maybe you should use module `PIL`/`pillow` to work with images or `numpy` to work with images as arrays ? Today was question [how to stich image in one image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041928/multiple-pngs-pdfs-per-page-using-python) and I shows how to do it with `PIL`/`pillow` or `Wand` or `numpy`

Comment: to repeate it you would have to use loops - i,e `for targetX in range(100, 501, 200)` `for targetY in range(100, 501, 200)`