# Multiple pngs/pdfs per page using python

Tags: python, pdf, png

I have a set of images I have saved as .png and .pdf. I was wondering if there is anyway to combine either the pngs or pdfs together in such a way I could have multiple per page. I know how to use PdfFileMerger() to merge several pdfs together, but this only puts one item per page. Is there any way to accomplish this? I have both pdfs and pngs so whichever one I need to use I can.

I basically want to do something like:

Take image1.png, 
image2.png, 
image3.png, and 
image4.png and create something like:

outputfile1:

```
-----------------------------
              |
              |
image1.png    | image2.png
              |
              |
-----------------------------
              |
              |
image3.png    | image4.png
              |
              |
-----------------------------
```

I would really appreciate it!

Comment: why not read the images and re-plot them the way you want?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I searched for a while trying to find something with little luck

Comment: matplotlib has imread and imshow functions

Comment: ahh I see. I am assuming it is similar to when you do subplots when graphing?

Comment: yes you can do 2x2 subplots and arrange your images that way..there might be a more direct way but I know this would work for sure

Comment: Okay perfect. I will check that out!

Comment: you can use `PIL`/`pillow` to works with images. You create big empty image and use `paste()` to put images in selected places. OR probably you could use `cv2` to read them as numpy arrays and join arrays.

Comment: instead of Python you can use program [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) - it can `combine`/`montage` images in command line. Eventually you can use these commands in python with `os.system()` or `subprocess`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `PIL`/`pillow` to create big empty image and then put small images on this image in different places.

```
from PIL import Image

# get images    
img1 = Image.open('image1.png')
img2 = Image.open('image2.png')
img3 = Image.open('image3.png')
img4 = Image.open('image4.png')

# get width and height
w1, h1 = img1.size
w2, h2 = img2.size
w3, h3 = img3.size
w4, h4 = img4.size

# to calculate size of new image 
w = max(w1, w2, w3, w4)
h = max(h1, h2, h3, h4)

# create big empty image with place for images
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (w*2, h*2))

# put images on new_image
new_image.paste(img1, (0, 0))
new_image.paste(img2, (w, 0))
new_image.paste(img3, (0, h))
new_image.paste(img4, (w, h))

# save it
new_image.save('new.png')
```

BTW: you could write it in `for`-loop(s).

---

The same with program [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) without Python.

But you can use these commands in Python with `os.system('convert ...')`

```
$ convert image1.png image2.png +append row1.png
$ convert image3.png image4.png +append row2.png
$ convert row1.png row2.png -append new.png
```

`+append` join in row, `-append` join in column.

It is possible to do it even in one command: [Stitching Image Set Together](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33581)

```
$ convert image1.png image2.png image3.png image4.png +append -crop 2x1@ -append new.png
```

If you use `new.pdf` instead of `new.png` then it can create `PDF`

---

There is Python module [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org) which uses `ImageMagick`. Code is similar to `pillow`.

```
from wand.image import Image

img1 = Image(filename='image1.png')
img2 = Image(filename='image2.png')
img3 = Image(filename='image3.png')
img4 = Image(filename='image4.png')

w1, h1 = img1.size
w2, h2 = img2.size
w3, h3 = img3.size
w4, h4 = img4.size

w = max(w1, w2, w3, w4)
h = max(h1, h2, h3, h4)

new_image = Image(width=w*2, height=h*2)

new_image.composite(image=img1, left=0, top=0)
new_image.composite(image=img2, left=w, top=0)
new_image.composite(image=img3, left=0, top=h)
new_image.composite(image=img4, left=w, top=h)

new_image.save(filename='new.png')
```

---

Example with `cv2` and `numpy` but it works when images have the same size. If they have different then they need empty rows and columns to have the same size.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('image1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('image2.png')
img3 = cv2.imread('image3.png')
img4 = cv2.imread('image4.png')

row1 = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
row2 = np.concatenate((img3, img4), axis=1)
new_image = np.concatenate((row1, row2))

# or
row1 = np.hstack((img1, img2))
row2 = np.hstack((img3, img4))
new_image = np.vstack((row1, row2))

cv2.imwrite('new.png', new_image)
```

Similar with `matplotlib` and `numpy`

```
import matplotlib.image
import numpy as np

img1 = matplotlib.image.imread('image1.png')
img2 = matplotlib.image.imread('image2.png')
img3 = matplotlib.image.imread('image3.png')
img4 = matplotlib.image.imread('image4.png')

row1 = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
row2 = np.concatenate((img3, img4), axis=1)
new_image = np.concatenate((row1, row2))

# or
row1 = np.hstack((img1, img2))
row2 = np.hstack((img3, img4))
new_image = np.vstack((row1, row2))

matplotlib.image.imsave('new.png', new_image)
```

Similar with `imageio` and `numpy`

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

img1 = imageio.imread('image1.png')
img2 = imageio.imread('image2.png')
img3 = imageio.imread('image3.png')
img4 = imageio.imread('image4.png')

row1 = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
row2 = np.concatenate((img3, img4), axis=1)
new_image = np.concatenate((row1, row2))

# or
row1 = np.hstack((img1, img2))
row2 = np.hstack((img3, img4))
new_image = np.vstack((row1, row2))

imageio.imwrite('new.png', new_image)
```

Comment: I will try this out! Thank you!

Comment: I added example with ImageMagick

Comment: I added examples with `numpy` and `cv2`, `matplotlib`, `imageio`

Comment: If you use `new.pdf` instead of `new.png` in `convert`  then it can create `PDF`

Comment: this is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: there is Python module [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org) which uses `ImageMagick` but I don't know how to use it to concatenate images.

Comment: I added `Wand` example after `ImageMagick` example.